# how to create random request time delay in sqlmap?

Tags: penetration-test, sql-injection, sqlmap, black-hat, cyber-warfare

How can i configure sql-map to try payloads at random time delay?
as an example time between first and second request can be 0.10s and second and third might 0.25 and so on.

i know there is --delay option but it takes static value.

Comment: What's your goal in doing this? And how many of those tags are actually relevant to your question?

Comment: well i am learning penetration testing and for that purpose i am using raven2 ctf from vulnhub website. one potential parameter is showing request conflict due to large number of request sqlmap is sending nearly same time. thats why.

Comment: @thunder a simple static delay should solve that.Random delay wont have effect.

Comment: @thunder maybe its supposed to solved manually.

Comment: yeah but problem is if i create less delay than it will conflict and if more delay than request time out, thats why i want to try random time delay.

Comment: @VipulNair yeah you are right. to root raven2 i had to exploit another vulneribility which doesnt require sql injection .

Comment: this should solve it 
https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/issues/2256